# Unable to set Spinner selection value with object

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I have a `spinner` like this:

```
 List<Vehicle> vehicles = dataSource.getAllVehicles();
 Spinner spVehicle = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spVehicle);
 SpinnerVehicleAdapter sAdapter = new SpinnerVehicleAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_textview, vehicles);
 spVehicle.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

I want to preselect the dropdown value of the spinner so I THINK I have to preselect it with **a matching `Vehicle` Object**, right?

Keep in mind, this is inside of an `ArrayAdapter<Oil>` where I have access to this:

```
Oil oilChange;
oilChange.getVehicleId();
```

So, with that info, I try to set it like this:

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle(getContext(), oilChange.getVehicleId());
int spinnerPostion = sAdapter.getPosition(v);
spVehicle.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
```

**Here are supplementary methods:** (I believe I have confirmed below code is not the issue.)

```
public Vehicle(Context mContext, int vehicleId) {

    GasDataSource datasource = new GasDataSource(mContext);
    datasource.open();
    Vehicle vehicle = datasource.createVehicle(vehicleId);

    this.vehicleName = vehicle.getVehicleName();
    this.vehicleYear = vehicle.getVehicleYear();
    this.vehicleModel = vehicle.getVehicleModel();
    this.vehicleMake = vehicle.getVehicleMake();
    this.oilDistance = vehicle.getOilDistance();
    this.drivenDistance = vehicle.getDrivenDistance();

    datasource.close();
}
```

And then:

```
public Vehicle createVehicle(long id) {

    if (!database.isOpen()) {
        open();
    }

    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_VEHICLE, allVehColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_VEHICLE_ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        vehicle = cursorToVehicle(cursor);
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return vehicle;
}
```

Now the `spinner` dropdown in question uses the property `vehicle.vehicleName`;

And I have a:

```
  public String toString() {return getVehicleName(); }
```

...in my vehicle class as well.

Also, I do not get a crash, I am simply am not able to set selection based on vehicle object provided.

**With logging I have confirmed** that I am creating the correct object based on the list row.  So my `SQL` is good.  But I return -1 in the `spinnerPosition`.

Can this work in my method?  Or do I have to match on `String`s not `Object`s?

**EDIT:  THIS IS MY WORKING CODE**

```
  Vehicle v = dataSource.findVehicle(oilChange.getVehicleId(), vehicles);
  if (v != null) {
       int spinnerPostion = sAdapter.getPosition(v);
       spVehicle.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
  }

public Vehicle findVehicle(long id, List<Vehicle> list) {
    for(Vehicle vehicle : list) {
        if(vehicle.getId() == id) {
            return vehicle;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Vehicle v = new Vehicle(getContext(), oilChange.getVehicleId()); 
> int spinnerPostion = sAdapter.getPosition(v);
> spVehicle.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
> ```

I think the code above that you are using is the problem.
You are using a new instance of Vehicle to get the position of the object
from the sAdapter.   ArrayAdapter.getPosition(T item) will only work if you
are getting an object that is part of the adapter and in your case that
would be the list from dataSource.getAllVehicles().

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = dataSource.getAllVehicles();
```

You will always get a -1 as the Vehicle you are looking for is a newly created
one and that is not in that list. Use the Vehicle instance that is part of the original list that you used. Probably, by creating a function in your datasource and passing the Vehicle ID and returning the Vehicle instance that you created when you called getAllVehicles.

Comment: Thanks, I created a lookup function by passing the `Vehicle` list and `id` and it returned back the correct `vehicle` and now the spinner is set accurately.

Answer (score 0):

instead of preselecting using the Vehicle object, try setting the index of the spinner

```
spVehicle.setSelection(intValueOfPreSelectedPosition);
```